# Does "gentle" have the figurative meaning of castrate?

Tags: meaning

In Robert Jordan's *The Wheel of Time* the male *Aes Sedai* (magicians or sorcerers) are being "gentled", because their magic use is dangerous for themselves and others.

I'm not a native speaker of English, but somehow I was of the impression that "gentle" is an euphemism for castration. The characters in the book aren't castrated, only their ability to use magic is removed, but if "gentle" means castrate, that would add to the feminist subtext of the novels.

So does "gentle" have the meaning of castration? The dictionaries I used don't have that meaning.

Comment: 'Gentle' and 'genital' have the same root. Now do your research on this :)

Comment: Gives a whole new meaning to "[Gentle on My Mind](https://youtu.be/VecunpIqlg0)".

Comment: https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Severing#Gentling seems to indicate that it’s used in the sense of taming animals, which would be an expected dictionary meaning.

Comment: _Gentle_ used to be a euphemism for _castrate_, for use when ladies were present (during the speech, not the castration).